# Extraordinary uses of Exceptions vs OOP rules

Tags: oop, exception

Me and my friend have some arguement about Exceptions. He proposes to use Exception as some kind of transporter for response (we can't just return it). I'm saying its contradictory to the OOP rules, he say it's ok because application flow was changed and information was passed.

Can you help us settle the dispute?

```
function example() {
    result = pdo.find();

    if (result) {
        e = new UniqueException();
        e.setExistingItem(result);

        throw new e;
    }
}

try {
    this.example();
} catch (UniqueException e) {
    this.response(e.getExistingItem());
}
```

Comment: No, exceptions should generally not be used soley as a control structure. That tends to lead to ugly hard to follow code.

Comment: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/189222/are-exceptions-as-control-flow-considered-a-serious-antipattern-if-so-why

Comment: Why can't you "just return it"? Sounds like you haven't tried hard enough. Using exceptions to propagate data is poisonously bad programming.

Comment: @tadman we use old framework, example() method is validation(return boolean) that is fired on model save: save()->validate()->fire all validations method. There is no way to just "return" it.

Comment: A) Why are you returning things from a validation method other than what you're supposed to be returning? B) Why can't you just stick that data somewhere else, like a property on an object?

Comment: @tadman Thanks for replay but as I said, we just argue about his idea - is it good or bad - nothing else matters :D

Comment: No doubt about it. This idea of returning things with exceptions is all-caps **BAD**.

Answer (score 0):

Using exceptions for application flow is a misleading practice. Anyone else (even you) maintaining that code will be puzzled because the function of the exception in your flow is totally different to the semantic of exceptions.

I imagine the reason you're doing this is because you want to return different results. For that, create a new class `Result`, that holds all information and react to it via an `if`-statement.